# JavaScript - setInterval not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code (like always) but the setInterval in my code is not working. Any clue why? My code:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if ($("*:contains(':\\)')").length > 0) {
        replace();
    };
}, 300);
```

`$("*:contains(':\\)')").length > 0` reports `true` just to let you know :)

Tell me if you need more details. Thank you!

Comment: Please create a working copy

Comment: You are replacing... what exactly? You can't just call replace(); unless that's a function you created somewhere.

Comment: How do you know that $("*:contains(':\\)')").length > 0 reports true? Where is the "replace" function defined? Is it in scope of the callback?

Comment: @Wax I have it created.

Comment: @pacifier21 I ran it in the console

Comment: @csf30816. Well if you have it defined, then it should be working just fine.

Comment: So, your callback should be getting invoked more than 3 times per second... Is that how fast you want it to happen? What does it say if you put something like "console.log(typeof replace)" within the if () {} block? If it says "undefined" then it is a scope problem. It should say "function" over and over (at least 3 times per second)

Comment: The setInterval is working perfectly from what I'm seeing. Therefore I assume the problem is not caused by setInterval, instead it is caused by a error occurring within the setInterval, possibly in the replace() function.

Comment: The function works. I call the replace function before setInterval

Comment: @pacifier21 Nothing shows up when I put it in the `if`

Comment: Just because you can call `$("*:contains(':\\)')").length > 0` in the console doesn't mean the DOM is loaded and that returns properly when the code is executed. I would make sure that that object is indeed in the dom when this javascript runs.

Comment: @pacifier21 ok, it reports `undefined`

Comment: @Georgemayer OK. How would I do this?

Comment: Is your javascript wrapped in a document ready?  ```$(function() {setInterval(function(){
    if ($("*:contains(':\\)')").length > 0) {
        replace();
    };
}, 300);})```

Comment: Alternatively, log this right above your `if`, to confirm `console.log($("*:contains(':\\)')").length > 0)`

Comment: @Georgemayer it is wrapped in `window.onload = function () {`

Comment: it seems that your code is incomplete.Try make your question more clear.

Comment: What happens when you log `$("*:contains(':\\)')").length > 0` above your `if`?

Comment: Since console.log(typeof replaced) reports "undefined", it means that the "replaced" function is not in scope of your setInterval callback. Without seeing how the "replaced" function is defined, it is hard to say why it can not be accessed within the setInterval callback.

Answer (score 1):

Woohoo! I fixed it using the following code (based on Arun Sivan's solution):

```
var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link  = document.createElement('script');
link.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js';
head.appendChild(link);

$(document).ready(function(){
    function replace() {
        // Lot's of code
    }

    replace();

    function check() {
        if ($("*:contains(':\\)')").length > 0) {
            replace();
        };
    }

    setInterval(check, 300);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `setInterval function`. if this does'nt solve your problem please try to share a `JSFiddle`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){$('.myTail').append("="); }, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myTail"> -:(my tail is growing)===</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Testing this now.